# After Initializing "npm init", I fill the every requirements, when come "Is This ok? (yes)" in cmd, Nothing is happening

Tags: node.js, express

Nothing is happening after pressing enter when come **Is This ok? (yes)** in bash. please help. I install NodeJs Currectly. please see the below image to better understand.
[image]

Comment: All the above steps can be bypassed with `npm init -y`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of "yes", 'y' or 'Y' you should press "Enter"
(I have also run 'npm install' may be this have helped)

```
`Is this ok? (yes)

C:\Users\MyName\Documents\How\tutorialcode>
C:\Users\MyName\Documents\How\tutorialcode>yes
'yes' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

[Solved]
Just use **Windows command prompt** to execute the command. It works fine.

And obviously, firstly you should go to the Project directory in my case **(C:/Project/iochat)**. After that execute the commands.